# Sorting by different meta keys woocommerce/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

let's say I have 3 products.

Woocommerce has default meta_key: _price which shows a regular price.

**Product A**: meta_key: _price, value: 80

**Product B**: meta_key: _price, value: 90, meta_key: _custom_price, value: 70

**Product C**: meta_key: _price, value: 100

When doing ASC sorting my expectations: B, A, C

But it sorts by _price: A, B, C

Any ideas how to fix that?

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'custom_price' => array(
            'key' => '_custom_price',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        'price' => array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'custom_price' => 'ASC',
        'price' => 'ASC'
    ),
));

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: You need to add custom hook to modify sorting clause. 
https://asarosenberg.se/code/sorting-wordpress-posts-by-several-numeric-custom-fields/

Comment: @VickyP thanks for reply! I tried it but it's not working... any ideas why? 

function customorderby($orderby) {
    return '_price.meta_value DESC, _meta_price.meta_value+0 DESC';
}
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'meta_key'  => '_price',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_price'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_meta_price',
        ),
    )
);
add_filter('posts_orderby','customorderby');
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter('posts_orderby','customorderby');

Answer (score 0):

Try this custom query and set order (ASC/DESC) as per requirement

```
$sql = "
SELECT *, GREATEST( m1.meta_value, m2.meta_value) AS sell_price,
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m1
ON (wp_posts.ID = m1.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m2
ON (wp_posts.ID = m2.post_id )
WHERE wp_posts.post_type   = 'product'
AND   wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND ( m1.meta_key = '_price' )
AND ( m2.meta_key = '_custom_price')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY sell_price
ASC";

$products = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

print_r($products);
```